# Chrome Extension stats for more than 3 months

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

On the chrome web store developer dashboard, there is a stats option that allows you to see graphs for impressions, total users, and uninstallations. The problem is that these graphs only go back 3 months, I would like graphs that go back longer.
I am wondering if there is a website that can show me longer graphs or stats.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to export data for more than 3 months. But if you want to check impressions it is easy to [integrate with google analytics](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/faq?hl=en-US#faq-app-06).

Comment: I feel like easy is a relative term in this instance...