# chrome webstore - extensions statistic for more than 3 months

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store, webstore

It seems that the statistic page for a Chrome Web Store extension (accessed from the developer dashboard - then clicking on "statistics") only display 3 months of data (in a .csv format)
Is there a way to retrieve more than 3 months of data. For instance, one year of statistic (or all-2018 for example)?

[Chrome web extension statistic page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLgpG.png)

Comment: Based on this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43882293/5995040), I think there is no way to see or export data more than 3 months. Also try using Google Analytics as suggested in the post.